# Why are some of my mongoose models not loading? Apparently they're not there

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm loading my mongoose models and some of them load, while others apparently don't load at all.

For instance,

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
var Friend = require('../models/Friends.js');
OR var Friend = mongoose.model('Friends');
```

If I console.log(Friend). I get an empty object. However, if I console log the other models, they exist. I created them EXACTLY the same way. I've been having some issues creating new mongoose models for some reason. Any ideas?

This is my friends.js file, which is exactly the same as the rest.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var FriendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    updateFrequency: Number,
    email: String,
    pastInteraction: [],
    lastTime: Date

});

FriendSchema.methods.updateLastAccess = function(cb){
    this.lastTime = new Date();
    this.save(cb);
}



mongoose.model('Friends', FriendSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting anything from friends.js

Export the Friends model from there

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var FriendSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    updateFrequency: Number,
    email: String,
    pastInteraction: [],
    lastTime: Date

});

FriendSchema.methods.updateLastAccess = function(cb){
    this.lastTime = new Date();
    this.save(cb);
}



module.exports =mongoose.model('Friends', FriendSchema);
```

After making this change you can console.log() and check

```
var Friend = require('../models/Friends.js');
console.log(Friend) ;
```

> Why am I able to access the other models in the same way? I haven't
>   exported yet I'm able to access them.

because you are creating a model at the spot on same file for them like `mongoose.model('Post');`

Comment: Why am I able to access the other models in the same way? I haven't exported yet I'm able to access them.

Comment: Glad to hear that it does, pleasure :)